# Building and Deploying ASP.NET website industry standard

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution with ASP.NET web site application and 10 class libraries. My requirement is to build and deploy the application automatically in QA web server every day at 5:00 pm. Also I have different *web.config* files for local machine & QA machine.

Looks like there are so many ways in which people are doing it.

1. MS Build definition
2. TFS Build definition & Workflow based definition
3. Web deployment projects in Visual Studio 2010
4. Pointing solution file (rather than build file) in TFS build queue

What is the industry standard on this and the best way for doing this? Can some one point out step by step of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The *best* way? It's whatever your team feel most comfortable working with in your particular deployment environment. In the same way that there's no "industry standard" deployment infrastructure there's no "industry standard" in deployment.

Just for configuration alone I've seen teams

- use a custom batch file run on a server to pull code from a network share, then search and replace tokens in config files
- use a Powershell script to pull code from a Nexus repository, search and replace for tokens, then use PSExec to invoke another Powershell script on a server to pull the tokenised code
- create custom Nant scripts that replace configuration files referenced as includes in `web.config`, then copy to the host
- copy and adjust configuration files by hand

All had their particular advantages in their situation: for instance, the system that had hand-rolled configuration files had a trivial lightly-used internal site deployed only a couple of times a year. It really wasn't worth building elaborate, complex automated deployment.

So I would suggest you take a careful look at what you and your team actually need, the time you have available, and how much automation you reckon you can afford.

Useful tools in the armoury include:

- *Web configuration transforms* that can transform `web.config` files depending on the build configuration in use. Reference on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx -- these are relatively new and work well once you've got the syntax sorted out.
- *Windows Powershell*, an awesome scripting language that's dynamic but which has *all* of .NET under the covers.
- `MSBuild`, which you can't avoid in Microsoft systems

My personal preference is to build slightly more automation that you think you initially need, especially for new systems that need frequent deployments to fix issues.